# Can I use 1333 MHz RAM in a 1067 MHz MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I've got a MacBook Pro from mid 2010 (6,2) and there is 2GB DDR3 RAM at 1067 MHz installed. I want to upgrade to 8GB but with 1333MHz as speed. Is this possible? Can my Mac support this kind of speed or will it generate a lot of erros and kernel panics?

I already saw there were multiple topics about this, but none of them seem to answer the 1067-1333MHz clearly...

**EDIT: Will [this](http://be.ingrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/ProductDetails.aspx?id=BE01@@4440@@10@@000000000001041154) memory fit my Mac with 100% certainty and without any issues?**

Comment: My late 2009 MacBook is running 4 gb of ddr3 1333 ram without an issue.. Works a treat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mid 2010 MBPs (7,1) with Geforce 320M are known for freezing when using faster ram. Motherboard chipset supports it, but graphics chip doesn't and OSX freezes when initializes the graphics.

My recommendation - buy 1066MHz DDR3. If you can't find it in your local store, try [OWC](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade/DDR3), it's a reputable online store that guarantees compatible ram at good prices.

ps. I'm not in any way connected with OWC.

Comment: I've got a MacBook Pro6,2 but with the same Geforce card... So I guess your answer applies to my Mac as well...

Comment: Actually it should be 330M. Better get 1066MHz ram, faster ram _could_ lead to problems.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a 1067 speed. I just double checked the data... But I guess the issues will still happen? And why do you say *could*?

Comment: The chipset of the MBP6,2 is different and the problem could be fixed (down clocking the bus speed to 1066). Even if this doesn't work you could reprogram the chips themselves (which is pita and does not always work). I should have used the _would_ not _could_.

Comment: Could you take a look at my edit please? Will this kind of RAM cause issues on my Mac?

Comment: Yes, this ram is within specs and should work. Newegg has positive reviews from mbp 2010 users.

Comment: Ah, crap... The 1333MHz just got delivered before I could cancel it... Are you *sure* it will cause issues? Do you have any background information about this topic?

Comment: @Michiel I have a Mid-2010 13" MBP. There are lots of people online who say 1333 MHz will work, but mine would freeze during OS X boot while it was loading drivers (even though it passed memtest86). So, you would probably be better off returning it.

Comment: How about 330M is it working with 1333?

Answer (score 3):

i just tried to put into my Mac Mini 2010 which normally swallows 1033Mhz DDR3 ram modules 1333mhz modules of my newer late 2011 MBP and it happens as mentioned above, kernel panic, Mac won't start up. Don't do it! ;)

Answer (score 2):

To support [the point](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53342/54644) by @mspasov (sorry for unable to add comments), my MacBook Pro mid 2010 13" (MacBookPro7,1) did not support Hynix 4GB PC3-12800 DDR3 1600 MHz sticks if used alone or 4GB+4GB, they work only if coupled (2GB+4GB) with pre-installed 2GB 1033 MHz sticks from Samsung.

Comment: same here, just tried it, thanks for the tip, I thought both memories were unusable

Answer (score 1):

I tried 1333Mhz RAM in my 2009 MacBook Pro 5,5.

It seemed to work for days or even a week, but I had sporadic Kernel Panics and memory corruption Issues.

I was completely stumped. Then I used an SPD editor on a Windows Notebook to set the default frequency of one of the modules to 1066Mhz which pulled the other one down as well. Now its working perfectly.

So due to NOT being able to change any settings of the RAM, I do not recommend to deviate from the recommended RAM specifications.