# Apple Macbook Mid 2010 Ram Upgrade & Equipment & Windows Compatibility

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

Now I have 2 gb (1gb x2) as standard I want to upgrade it. "Hi-Level 4GB 1066MHz DDR3 Notebook Ram (HLV-SOPC8500D3/4G)" is it okay to be upgraded? and after I replaced that one with one of my standard ram should I dislocate the other one? I mean can I use 5 gb ram (4+1) ?

And my second question is about removing process. Which equipments I'll need? If it is not obligatory I don't want to buy as a kit. Could anybody name these equipments I need?

Finally, will 16 gb or 8 gb RAM work for windows (dual-boot) properly? (LAST QUESTION DID NOT ANSWERED YET)

Answer (score 1):

Your Macbook 2010 will be fine if you buy 2x8gb of 1066mHz DDR3. You will dual boot without issues. Correct ram speed is important, see my answer to a similar question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53342/4474) about possible issues with faster ram.

You will need Philips #00 screw to upgrade your memory. There is also a great guide at [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Unibody+Model+A1342+RAM+Replacement/1666).

Comment: oups... The laptop looks different in the link you send me. Is there a possibility that laptop is not mid 2010? because mine is white and bottom cover is completely different. 7,1 is written in system information for me. Is it right?

Comment: My mistake - you have the polycarbonate one - MacBook 7,1. (It's an almost identical to MacBook Pro 7,1. I have changed my answer and links to the correct article.

Answer (score 0):

This [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht1651) document details what you need to remove and replace the RAM.

Using the wrong spec RAM can cause serious problems. The specs for the RAM are very specific: 204-pin PC3-8500 (1066MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM

Apple spec is for max of 4GB RAM, but it use 16GB with Mac OS X 10.7.5 or later and the latest EFI firmware update.

DataMemorySystems has [inexpensive RAM](http://www.datamemorysystems.com/apple-macbook-intel-core-2-duo-2-4ghz-13-white-unibody-mc516ll/a-mid-2010-memory-upgrades/) for this model.

Disclosure: I'm a satisfied customer of DataMemorySystems, as is my employer. We have purchased most, if not all of our RAM upgrades for hundreds of laptops & desktops (Mac & PC) from DataMem.

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply. 16 Gb with mac os x 10.7.5 or later okay got it but what about windows? Does this os also support 16gb or 8 gb ram?

Comment: Windows? I don't understand. This is an Apple site.

Comment: Dual boot I mean. I have mac os x as main os normally. It won't effect windows negative right? I think I'll buy that one if it is okay : http://www.datamemorysystems.com/dm50-223-1-x-2/

Comment: I have no practical experience with dual-boot stuff: I'm a Mac guy through and through. You should edit your question to include the dual-boot aspect of your situation and ask if all 16GB will be used by Windows. You should certainly purchase RAM that is compatible with the hardware.

Comment: mid 2010 macbook pros (I assume 13') do not work with 16gb of ram.